# How can I put multi configmap in the same mount path in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have two python files, `testing_1.py` and `testing_2.py`.
Then, I have created the configmap with `testing-config1` to store `testing_1.py` and `testing-config2` to store `testing_2.py` respectively.

In Kubernetes yaml,

```
...
      containers:
      - name: spark-master
        image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
        volumeMounts:
        - name: testing
          mountPath: /jobs
        - name: testing2
          mountPath: /jobs
      volumes:
        - name: testing
          configMap:
            name: testing-config1
        - name: testing2
          configMap:
            name: testing-config2
...
```

In the final result, the path only contains testing_1.py.

Comment: What exactly structure you'd like to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by providing `subPath` while specifying path. Change it as below:

```
containers:
      - name: spark-master
        image: bde2020/spark-master:2.4.4-hadoop2.7
        volumeMounts:
        - name: testing
          mountPath: /jobs/testing_1.py
          subPath: testing_1.py
        - name: testing2
          mountPath: /jobs/testing_2.py
          subPath: testing_2.py
      volumes:
        - name: testing
          configMap:
            name: testing-config1
        - name: testing2
          configMap:
            name: testing-config2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put both files in the same ConfigMap.

Or, use a [projected](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected) volume:

> A projected volume maps several existing volume sources into the same
>   directory.
>
> Currently, the following types of volume sources can be projected:
>
> - secret
> - downwardAPI
> - configMap
> - serviceAccountToken